# How to avoid massive gap between sections when using the command clearpage?

Tags: sectioning, clearpage

I am trying to avoid the massive gaps between the sections. Section 2 should start on page 87 instead of page 88. Does anyone know, how to fix this? Thank you in advance!

This is my code:

```
\begin{document}
...
\section{1}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Versuchohneacc1024_FFT.eps}}
  \hfill
  \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Versuchohnacc1024_STFT.eps}}
  \caption[Ergebnisse der FFT \& STFT mit einem idealen Messsignal bei einer Analyse von 1024 Samples]{Ergebnisse der FFT \& STFT}
  \label{fig:Start}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Versuchohneacc1024_FFT.eps}}
  \hfill
  \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Versuchohnacc1024_STFT.eps}}
  \caption[Ergebnisse der FFT \& STFT mit einem idealen Messsignal bei einer Analyse von 1024 Samples]{Ergebnisse der FFT \& STFT}
  \label{fig:Start}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Versuchohneacc1024_FFT.eps}}
  \hfill
  \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Versuchohnacc1024_STFT.eps}}
  \caption[Ergebnisse der FFT \& STFT mit einem idealen Messsignal bei einer Analyse von 1024 Samples]{Ergebnisse der FFT \& STFT}
  \label{fig:Start}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Versuchohneacc1024_FFT.eps}}
  \hfill
  \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Versuchohnacc1024_STFT.eps}}
  \caption[Ergebnisse der FFT \& STFT mit einem idealen Messsignal bei einer Analyse von 1024 Samples]{Ergebnisse der FFT \& STFT}
  \label{fig:Start}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Versuchohneacc1024_FFT.eps}}
  \hfill
  \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Versuchohnacc1024_STFT.eps}}
  \caption[Ergebnisse der FFT \& STFT mit einem idealen Messsignal bei einer Analyse von 1024 Samples]{Ergebnisse der FFT \& STFT}
  \label{fig:Start}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\section{2}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: we can't run your code example and the image is just a lot of green crossing out so it is rather hard to guess your issue. It would be much easier if you posted a real example that showed your issue, you can use dummy text and `example-image` as the image.

Comment: really is hard to guess why you got the layout but as a start I would replace all `[!ht]` by `[tp]` (or simply remove the option)  `!` means special-case override the constraints designed to force good layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell with no example, but I think your document is showing

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaa

\section{1}
\begin{figure}[!ht]  \centering  \rule{5pt}{.25\textheight}  \caption{zzz}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]  \centering  \rule{5pt}{.25\textheight}  \caption{zzz}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]  \centering  \rule{5pt}{.25\textheight}  \caption{zzz}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]  \centering  \rule{5pt}{.25\textheight}  \caption{zzz}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]  \centering  \rule{5pt}{.25\textheight}  \caption{zzz}\end{figure}
\clearpage
\section{2}
\end{document}
```

Note that `!` means to override the constraints that are designed to prevent misplaced figures. It is useful in special cases but it isn't helping here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaaa\\
aaa

\section{1}
\begin{figure}[htp]  \centering  \rule{5pt}{.25\textheight}  \caption{zzz}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]  \centering  \rule{5pt}{.25\textheight}  \caption{zzz}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]  \centering  \rule{5pt}{.25\textheight}  \caption{zzz}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htp]  \centering  \rule{5pt}{.25\textheight}  \caption{zzz}\end{figure}

\clearpage
\begin{figure}[htp]  \centering  \rule{5pt}{.25\textheight}  \caption{zzz}\end{figure}
\section{2}
\end{document}
```